# GRASS GIS: Execute SQL query and save output

Tags: postgis, postgresql, grass-gis, grass.script

I'm trying to find a way in GRASS GIS to execute a complex SQL query (with JOINs) and save it.

```
SELECT a.id, a.geom
FROM schema01.table01 a
JOIN schema01.table02 b
ON a.geom && b.geom AND ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom)
WHERE b.id IN ('100', '101')
```

The only solution I've found is to put the complex logic inside the where parameter of the v.in.ogr module:

```
gs.run_command(
    'v.in.ogr',
    input='PG:host=localhost dbname=dbname user=user port=5432 password=password',
    layer='schema01.table01',
    output='output',
    where="""
        id IN (
            SELECT a.id
            FROM schema01.table01 a
            JOIN schema01.table02 b
            ON a.geom && b.geom AND ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom)
            WHERE b.id IN ('100', '101')
        )
    """
)
```

In my opinion, this isn't a nice solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run an SQL query against a PostgreSql database (As I understand your need)

You can use the basic Qgis tool :

it's located in Database Manager menu in Qgis,
you write the connection to your database
would be something like :

host : localhost;
port : 5432;
password : password;
user : postgres;
dbname : dbname;

after that , you connect to your database and click the button "execute query"
you then have a window where you can run your query

if you want to save your result, you can create a table within your PostgresSql database

for your example :

```
create table public.result as (
SELECT a.id, a.geom
FROM schema01.table01 a
JOIN schema01.table02 b
ON a.geom && b.geom AND ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom)
WHERE b.id IN ('100', '101')
)
```

this way you will create a table with the desired output that you may view with Qgis

extensive tutorial for Qgis + PostgresSql use : https://www.line-45.com/post/using-qgis-postgis-dynamic-duo

what you are looking for is under : Running Queries with the SQL Window

hope this answer your question, feel free to refine it

edit : I did not pay attention to the grass-script tag , maybe one solution if you want to keep it script-wise would be to open a psycopg connector to the database and run the query from it, I don't know if you can create tables from Grass API

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but QGIS isn't an option for me, because the sql query is part of a pretty large python script, that uses a lot of GRASS GIS modules. psycopg would work, but I think it's kind of complicated (and slow) to import geometries from Python into GRASS GIS. I think I will just use the workaround I described in my question. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: ok, what do you mean by import geometries from Python into Grass GIS ?

Comment: Let's say I have a shapely MultiPolygon geometry and I want to rasterize the geometry with grass-script. From my understanding you can't just use the shapely geometry as a parameter in the grass-script rasterize module. Instead you have to save the geometry (for example as a GeoPackage), import the GeoPackage into the GRASS GIS Session and then you can use the geometry in the grass-script rasterize module.

Comment: Your explanation make sense , you will indeed need to save your data before using it with the gs command to rasterize it. Your datasource (GeoPackage) can also by modified by another connector that would be more suited to your need (sqlite3 in this case), I feel like you would benefit from doing the join outside of the grass "where" clause and use a sqlite connector to directly change your data before hand. Then use your gs command on the result created by this other query, performance should be the same